FillPath oddly merges AddArc into a shape
 BitmapImage = new Bitmap(width,height);
 Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BitmapImage);
 SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Purple);

 GraphicsPath myGraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();

 myGraphicsPath.AddArc(100,50,50,50,0,-180);
 myGraphicsPath.AddLine(new Point(100, 100), new Point(100, 200));

 myGraphicsPath.AddLine(new Point(150, 200), new Point(150, 75));
 myGraphicsPath.AddArc(100, 175, 50, 50, 0, 180);

 graphics.FillPath(solidBrush, myGraphicsPath);
 graphics.DrawPath(pen1, myGraphicsPath);

I wanted to draw a curved closed figure in winforms C#, but it didn't work out.
Here is what I wanted to draw
.
And what I got
.

What are you getting versus what were you expecting?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879957/losing-the-shape-i-have-drawn-in-windows-form

StartFigure - CloseFigure - CloseAllFigures.

Remove the two .AddLine methods, change the startAngle of the first arc to -180 .AddArc(100, 50, 50, 50, -180, 180);, add the second arc as is, close the figure  myGraphicsPath.CloseFigure();, and draw.
